# MVC 5 Web App with good JS practices (no Typescript you may use ES 2015)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want some advice. I am working on a test project that has some specifications that I wish to satisfy. I would like to know what my options are based on opinions. This `WebApp` will be making `api` calls to another `api` server.

Here are my specifications:
`MVC 5` `WebApp` with good `JS` practices (no `Typescript` you may use `ES 2015`). This should be hybrid (module `JS` calling server side code), no `SPA`.
- Use `bootstrap` to speed up `UI` development. 
- Use promises instead callbacks.

My thoughts are 
`ASP.NET MVC 5` with `Angularjs`
`ASP.NET MVC 5` with `Vue.js`

What other options can I consider?

Comment: You should go with ASP.NET MVC 5 with ReactJs.This is also good option.

Answer (score 2):

You have various options you know. You could combine ASP.NET MVC 5 with libraries/frameworks like Angular, Vue, and React.
I tend to lean more on Vue JS.
Also if you want to use React you might want to try Flow since you don't want TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to use TypeScript, don't go with angular. Better go with ASP.NET 5 MVC with React or Vue.js. You can also use ASP.NET Core MVC with React or Vue.js. I would prefer the second one.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 5 Stable  but if  its a new project go with core 2

i prefer 
ASP.NET Core 2  with Angularjs